# Hide twitter bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Following is my jquery code which i  am using to display `popover` .  What i wanna do is when a user click anywhere on the screen or on any `<span id="close" class="pover"></span>` then it hides the current opened popover and show a new popover on which the user clicks on.

As You can see below span which contains `class="pover"` are being poped up by the following jquery kindly let me know how can i hide the opened popup and display a new one accordingly

Currently, all the popover are getting displayed on click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pover').each(function() {
        //$('#close').popover( "hide" );
        $(this).popover({
            title: $(this).attr('abc'),
            content: $(this).attr('data-content'),
            delay: "show",
            trigger: "click"
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: You should put it on a jsfiddle

Comment: @macool I put it on fiddle but my code is not working there dont know why all the required js files are being added to here is the link to that http://jsfiddle.net/AFffL/372/

Comment: ANSWER:

http://www.leecarmichael.com/bootstrapx-clickover/examples.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this great solution:

Exactly what I am seeking to do.

https://github.com/lecar-red/bootstrapx-clickover

http://www.leecarmichael.com/bootstrapx-clickover/examples.html